# Request for member is Non-class type

Tags: c++, arduino-leonardo

Im getting this error:

```
iotHook.ino: In function 'void setup()':
iotHook:13: error: request for member 'begin' in 'esp', which is of non-class type 'Esp8266()'
request for member 'begin' in 'esp', which is of non-class type 'Esp8266()'
```

When I try to lunch my begin function of my class:

```
class Esp8266 {

  public:
    Esp8266();
    void begin(HardwareSerial *wifiCom, HardwareSerial *debugCom);
    ...
  private:

    HardwareSerial *wifiCom;
    HardwareSerial *debugCom;
    ...

}

Esp8266::Esp8266() {
}

void Esp8266::begin(HardwareSerial *wifiCom, HardwareSerial *debugCom) {
  this->wifiCom = wifiCom;
  this->debugCom = debugCom;

  this->debugCom->begin(115200);
  while (!this->debugCom) {
  ;
  }
}
```

[image]

EDIT 1:
Updated image with new code
[image]

Why is not picking up the begin function?

Comment: Remove the brackets from your constructor.

Comment: @Majenko You mean from this Esp8266::Esp8266() {} to Esp8266::Esp8266() ???

Comment: No, what Ignacio says. The constructor in your sketch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current problem is that the USB Serial interface of the Leonardo isn't a hardware serial device, it's a CDC/ACM device, and the class for that isn't HardwareSerial, it's Serial_.

So you can't pass it to a function that expects a HardwareSerial.

What you should be using, instead, is the Stream class.  That will allow you to pass any object that is based on the Stream class, such as HardwareSerial, Serial_, Client, etc.  Many different things, including serial and networking protocols, use Stream as their base class.

It does have the down side, though, that you have to initialize the Stream objects in your sketch (that is, do the Serial.begin(...) and Serial1.begin(...) in your sketch not your class) because the Stream class doesn't have the concept of a baud rate, and so no begin(baud) function.

This is what I mean:

```
class Esp8266 {

public:
    Esp8266();
    void begin(Stream &wifiCom, Stream &debugCom);
private:

    Stream *_wifiCom;
    Stream *_debugCom;

};

Esp8266::Esp8266() {
}

void Esp8266::begin(Stream &wifiCom, Stream &debugCom) {
    _wifiCom = &wifiCom;
    _debugCom = &debugCom;

    while (!_debugCom) {
        ;
    }
}

Esp8266 esp;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial1.begin(115200);
    esp.begin(Serial, Serial1);
}  // end of setup

void loop() {
}  // end of
```

Note, as well, my use of pass-by-reference (Stream &whatever) so you don't have to pass a pointer in your begin function.  Also notice the use of unique variable names in the class (I always prefix my member variables with `_`) so you don't have to keep putting `this->` in everywhere.

---

To be able to move the `.begin()` function inside your class you will have to use both `HardwareSerial` and `Serial_` object types within your class.  There's two ways this may be done.

First is [*dynamic casting*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast):

```
void Esp8266::begin(Stream &wifiCom, Stream *debugCom) {
    _wifiCom = &wifiCom;
    _debugCom = &debugCom;

    HardwareSerial *hard;
    Serial_ *cdc;

    if (hard = dynamic_cast<HardwareSerial*>(_wifiCom)) {
        hard->begin(115200);
    } else if (cdc = dynamic_cast<Serial_*>(_wifiCom)) {
        cdc->begin(115200);
    }

    if (hard = dynamic_cast<HardwareSerial*>(_debugCom)) {
        hard->begin(115200);
    } else if (cdc = dynamic_cast<Serial_*>(_debugCom)) {
        cdc->begin(115200);
    }

}
```

I haven't tested this, and I don't know if the Arduino's cut-down C++ library is even capable of it, but it's worth a try.

The other method is to *overload* the `.begin()` function of your class with multiple versions that take different parameters:

```
void Esp8266::begin(Serial_ &wifiCom, HardwareSerial *debugCom) {
    _wifiCom = &wifiCom;
    _debugCom = &debugCom;
    wifiCom.begin(115200);
    debugCom.begin(115200);
}

void Esp8266::begin(HardwareSerial &wifiCom, HardwareSerial *debugCom) {
    _wifiCom = &wifiCom;
    _debugCom = &debugCom;
    wifiCom.begin(115200);
    debugCom.begin(115200);
}

void Esp8266::begin(HardwareSerial &wifiCom, Serial_ *debugCom) {
    _wifiCom = &wifiCom;
    _debugCom = &debugCom;
    wifiCom.begin(115200);
    debugCom.begin(115200);
}
```

You're still storing them internally as `Stream` objects in all cases, but within the `begin()` function itself you also have them available as their child classes.  It does mean you have duplicate code copied between the different versions of `begin()`.  You could modularize it a little more though by moving the duplicated code into functions which would only need to be duplicated twice, not three times - one to act on a single `Serial_` object and one to act on a single `HardwareSerial` object:

```
void Esp8266::initSerial(Serial_ *ser) {
    ser->begin(115200);
}

void Esp8266::initSerial(HardwareSerial *ser) {
    ser->begin(115200);
}

void Esp8266::begin(Serial_ &wifiCom, HardwareSerial *debugCom) {
    _wifiCom = &wifiCom;
    _debugCom = &debugCom;
    initSerial(&wifiCom);
    initSerial(&debugCom);
}
... etc x3 ...
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the cleaner answer. Is not very clear to me why I have to initialize the stream object outside of my class. Is important to me because my code have a guessing routine inside my begin function that tries different baud rates till it finds the correct one (http://pastebin.com/GYjE48yj), since I cant use .begin(speed) inside my class, do you know any workaround?

Comment: @DomingoSL It's because the `.begin(baud)` function only exists in the `HardwareSerial` and `Serial_` child classes and not the `Stream` parent class.  You could try using *dynamic casting* to attempt to convert the `Stream` objects into first a `HardwareSerial` object and then (if that fails) a `Serial_` object, but how that would perform (if it's even possible) on an Arduino is anyone's guess. The other option is to provide multiple `begin()` functions or constructors that take all the possible different combinations of object types and deals with them accordingly.

Comment: @DomingoSL I have added more detail to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[You've confused the compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/877538/20862) by making it think that `esp` is a function that takes no arguments and returns a `Esp8266`. But the no-argument constructor is called by default, so you don't need the parens there regardless.

```
Esp8266 esp;
```

Comment: Updated code according to your answer but same error

Comment: Please check the edit I made

Comment: You do see that that's a completely different problem, right?

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```C++
esp.begin (Serial, Serial1);
```

Should be:

```C++
esp.begin (&Serial, &Serial1);
```

It is expecting a **pointer** to a HardwareSerial instance.

---

Also make the instantiation line:

```C++
Esp8266 esp;   // <--------- no brackets!
```

---

This compiles without errors for me:

```C++
class Esp8266 {

  public:
    Esp8266();
    void begin(HardwareSerial *wifiCom, HardwareSerial *debugCom);
  private:

    HardwareSerial *wifiCom;
    HardwareSerial *debugCom;

};

Esp8266::Esp8266() {
}

void Esp8266::begin(HardwareSerial *wifiCom, HardwareSerial *debugCom) {
  this->wifiCom = wifiCom;
  this->debugCom = debugCom;

  this->debugCom->begin(115200);
  while (!this->debugCom) {
  ;
  }
}

Esp8266 esp;

void setup ()
  {
  esp.begin (&Serial, &Serial1);
  }  // end of setup

void loop ()
  {
  }  // end of loop
```

---

I would rework to use references anyway, saves all that mucking around with pointers:

```C++
class Esp8266 {
  public:
    Esp8266(HardwareSerial & wifiCom, HardwareSerial & debugCom);
    void begin();
  private:
    HardwareSerial & wifiCom;
    HardwareSerial & debugCom;
  };

// constructor
Esp8266::Esp8266(HardwareSerial &wifiCom_, HardwareSerial &debugCom_)
  : wifiCom (wifiCom_), debugCom (debugCom_)
  {
  }

// initialize stuff
void Esp8266::begin()
{
  debugCom.begin(115200);
  while (!debugCom)
  {
  }
}

Esp8266 esp (Serial, Serial1);

void setup ()
{
  esp.begin ();
}  // end of setup

void loop ()
{
}  // end of loop
```

---

### Corrected for Leonardo

Sorry, my reply above was compiled for the Mega2560, I didn't notice the Leonardo tag.

Majenko is quite right, you need to rework for the Leonardo. My example using references can reduce down to this now:

```C++
class Esp8266 {
  public:
    Esp8266(Stream & wifiCom, Stream & debugCom)
      : wifiCom_ (wifiCom), debugCom_ (debugCom) { }

  private:
    Stream & wifiCom_;
    Stream & debugCom_;
  };

Esp8266 esp (Serial, Serial1);

void setup ()
{
  Serial.begin (115200);
  while (!Serial) { }
  Serial1.begin (115200);
  while (!Serial1) { }
}  // end of setup

void loop ()
{
}  // end of loop
```

By storing a Stream type you can still print to them, however you need to initialize in `setup`, not in the `begin` function, which now becomes redundant.

I agree about not using `this->` although my preference is for trailing underscores as the use of leading underscores is reserved in quite a few cases, depending on the location and capitalization.

Comment: Now the error is:Esp.h:42:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Serial_*' to 'HardwareSerial*'
no matching function for call to 'Esp8266::begin(Serial_*, HardwareSerial*)'

Comment: With arduino ide 1.6.5: Esp.h:42:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Serial_*' to 'HardwareSerial*'
no matching function for call to 'Esp8266::begin(Serial_*, HardwareSerial*)'

Comment: You're thinking double-underscore.  Builtin (predefined) macros have the format `__BLAH_BLAH` (sometimes with trailing `__` too)  although some older compiler versions have some non-standard ones with just one underscore (they are naughty).  Certainly for avr-gcc version 5.2.0 all the predefined macros (with the exception of `#define AVR 1`) are in the standardized double-underscore format.

Comment: According to the C++ Standard: `Reserved in the global namespaces: identifiers beginning with an underscore`. Thus all identifiers in *global namespace*, starting with an underscore, are reserved. Also reserved in *any context* are `identifiers beginning with an underscore and an uppercase letter`. In addition: `identifiers containing adjacent underscores (or "double underscore")`. So you are only one capitalization away from a reserved identifier, by using leading underscores. You might be tempted, for example, to make a class *constant* like `_ITEM_COUNT` which has now become reserved.

Comment: Reserved doesn't mean unavailable.  If you like, all my member variables are reserved - I don't want anyone else using them.  Any my constants are most static and ProperlyCapitalized (as are my class names) since they aren't reserved.

Comment: That is a completely different thing. `I don't want anyone else using them` You can achieve that by making them private. If you use a reserved identifier (which possibly becomes a #define) then you run the risk that a word like _FOO will be replaced by some define which the compiler-implementers are entitled to use, and then find all your code doesn't compile. Whatever your motives are, you should not be using reserved identifiers. There has to be a set of identifiers that compiler-writers can use. They have specified what they are. Use them at your peril in your own code.

Comment: As if I would ever be daft enough to use _FOO as a variable. And if I did use it as a macro it would complain during compilation. And you never expose member variables to the wider public - you always have them private (or at worst protected) and use getters and setters. You never use all capitals for variables either, that's just daft. So _FOO is never going to be a conflict, since my member variables would never even approach that format. In my past 30 years of programming I have never come across a conflict like you mention. That can't just down to luck, or I'd have won the lottery by now.

Comment: The issue is not whether or not you are daft. The issue is, do you follow the Standard, or not? Look, over the years I've written a lot of code with leading underscores, probably a hangover from the way Microsoft did it. So, *I* did it too - in the past. Of course, you are free to not follow the Standard. And you may never have a problem. But if you choose to use reserved identifiers, and one day one of them becomes `#define`d as some weird sequence of characters, you will be scratching your head as to why you get a compile error on what looks like a perfectly good line of code.